# Can't reference framework .h header files from my Swift controller

Tags: ios, swift, header-files

I'm trying to import a framework made up of `Objective-C` header files.
I've created a bridging file but when I try to import a header the compiler doesn't recognise it.

This is error Xcode is showing:
[image]

Also if I try to reference the Framework in my Swift file as `import ArcGIS` it doesn't recognise that either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to import ArcGIS header file. Guess you have used Carthage or CocoaPods. The only thing you need is to `import ArcGIS`

Check the documentation here

https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/swift/guide/install.htm